# Why `std::thread()` and `std::packaged_task()` works different, although they both accept callable targets?

Tags: c++, c++11, callable, stdthread, packaged-task

Here is a simple [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/f34YhhrbY):

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <functional>

void foo(int){}

int main()
{
    std::thread(foo, 1).join();                  //works indeed
    std::packaged_task<void(int)> task{foo, 1};  //complian
    std::packaged_task<void(int)> task{std::bind(foo, 1)};
}
```

[Both  `std::thread()` and `std::packaged_task()`  accept callable targets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task), why the code for `std::packaged_task()` is a little different? Why does not make the `std::packged_task()` works like `std::thread()`(i.e. accepts arguments like `std::thread`)?

> The class template std::packaged_task wraps any Callable target
> (function, lambda expression, bind expression, or another function
> object) so that it can be invoked asynchronously. Its return value or
> exception thrown is stored in a shared state which can be accessed
> through std::future objects.

Comment: The code is different because the contexts of execution are different. [`std::packaged_task`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task) is a template; [`std:;thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) is *not* a template. For `std::thread`, the callable type is *deduced*. For `std::packaged_task<>` that type is *specified* as a template argument. If you look at the [ctors for `std::packaged_task`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task/packaged_task) you'll find none which assemble the callable via perfect forwarding. Thus, your `bind` (or lambda).

Comment: @WhozCraig I think your comment worth a great answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig Could you please explain that in more detail? Both `std::thread` and `std::packaged_task` are template classes.

Comment: @John `std::thread` is not a template, `std::thread(foo, 1)` is a template constructor `std::thread::thread`.

Comment: @273K I still have difficulty in understanding it. I think they both have ***template*** keyword in their declarations.

Comment: Where? [std::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) has no "template" in the whole page content. `std::thread(foo, 1)` is an unnamed object, `std::packaged_task<void(int)>` is a type.

Comment: @273K The [third constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) is `template< class Function, class... Args >
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );`.

Comment: @John A class can have template member functions. `std::thread` is not a template, but it does have a template constructor. `std::packaged_task` is a class template (it also has template member functions)

Comment: @Caleth I fully understand what you mean. Since the declaration is [`template <class F, class Allocator>
explicit packaged_task( std::allocator_arg_t, const Allocator& a, F&& f );`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task/packaged_task), then why `std::packaged_task<void(int)> task{std::bind(foo, 1)}` works?  ` I think `std::bind(foo, 1)` ` matches the third parameter of said declaration other than the first one. How do you think about it?

Comment: @John that's not the only constructor of packaged_task. your call uses `template <class F> explicit packaged_task( F&& f );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::packaged_task` does not run a function/callable immediately, a function execution is deferred and parameters can be passed later to `void operator()( ArgTypes... args );`, therefore the possible constructor `template< class Function, class... Args > explicit packaged_task( Function&& f, Args&&... args );` is not necessary.

However `std::thread` runs a function/callable immediately, thus parameters must be passed to the constructor `template< class Function, class... Args > explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );`. You may consider it like sugar to avoid persistently writing code like `std::thread(bind(f, 1));` instead of convenient `std::thread(f, 1);`.